# How to reduce the breakage of hair, help to strengthen it and remove the dryness?

Tags: hair

How can I reduce the breakage of hair, help to strengthen it and remove the dryness?

When I brush my hair mostly hairs are comes with brush and as well as my hairs are full of dryness, I am more tens please tell me how can overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent dryness in hair, keep it well moisturised.

1. After washing hair, it will become very dry. Before applying oil, rinse it very lightly with a little cold water depending how much hair you have, let it absorb into the hair and then apply oil to lock in the moisture. Do this every time after washing.
2. Regularly wet your clean hands, run it through your hair. Then do the same with a little oil.

You can use any oil. Oilve oil, hair oil, or any other. I use johnsons baby oil, but if you're a girl you can use special hair oils from any supermarket.

Jatt